# Why doesn't "pip install" work in Anaconda 3.7?

Tags: python, pip, anaconda

I installed Anaconda 3.7 on Windows 10.
When I try to run **pip install xxx**
I get the following message:
*TypeError: 'module' object is not callable*

Any advice on how to solve this will be much appreciated.

Comment: `xxx` might be relevant here. Is it for any `xxx` ?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't matter what I try to install, I get the same message for everything.
There's no problem in 3.8.

Answer (score 0):

`'module' object is not callable` points to what `xxx` is as pointed out by @Lescurel.

You may be trying to access a class inside of the module (which wasn't added to their `__init__`) and need to change your import statement.

Try: `import xxx.class`
or
`from xxx import class`